# GitLab CI Pipeline on specific branch only

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to implement GitLab CI Pipelines to build and deploy an Angular app. In our project we have two general branches: `master` (for production only) and `develop`. For development we create `feature/some-feature` branches from `develop` branch. When development finished, we create merge request from `feature/some-feature` to `develop`. When merge request approved and merged into `develop` branch I want to run a Pipeline in order to build application and deploy the build on some environment.

I use the following setup in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:7.5-configured

stages:
    - build
    - deploy

build_job:
    stage: build
    only:
        - develop
    script:
        - /bin/bash <some script here>

...
```

The problem is that Pipeline executed every time I push into any `feature/some-feature` branch. What's wrong with my setup? How can I force the Pipeline to be executed **only** when push performed into `develop` branch directly?

**Solution**
It was my mistake - I had two different .gitlab-ci.yml files in `develop` branch and `feature/some-feature` branch.

Comment: I'm struggling with this too. I my stage is running always. The solutions below didn't help.

Comment: You need to use the `ref:` section under `only:`

Answer (score 26):

Although it has been passed much time on this discussion I would like to suggest an opinion, which I am using most of the time.

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: on_success
      changes:
        - folder/some_folder/**/* 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"'
      when: manual
      changes:
        - folder/some_other_folder/**/*
```

This structure solved my various problems, I hope it helps you to!

Regards.

Comment: It may help for the reader's if you explained why this is a better alternative. It would be appreciated

Comment: First of all, I am not saying that this is the best approach, everyone can use different approach. I am just saying this approach helped me a lot and yes I have not seen bugs/errors as much rather than the other approaches that I have tried. Anyway, [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually) is the link for the detailed documentation.

Answer (score 23):

It was my mistake - I had two different .gitlab-ci.yml files in `develop` branch and `feature/some-feature` branch and that's why the Pipeline was executed for all branches.

Answer (score 7):

You can also define the rule at the global level instead of job if you want

Here is the example for that

```
image: python:3.8

stages:
 - test

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development" || ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && ( $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "development" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" ))

unit_test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:13.4
  before_script:
    - export PYTHONPATH=$PWD
   script:
    - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
    - python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
```

Answer (score -9):

You should add the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the branch you need to run the CI on.

Comment: But then I need to add it to .gitignore as well, right? Otherwise it will overwrite the .gitlab-ci.yml in the master branch when I merge.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The .gitlab-ci-yml file will eventually end up on other branches because they're creating new branches from development and merging into development. I'm not sure about the .gitignore comment but that file isn't really meant for this.