# Gitlab ci, run job using Dockerfile

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab ci workflow where one of the steps creates a container. I manage to make it run only if the `Dockerfile` file has changes but now it also runs every time that I create a new branch.
Currently I am including this in my job:

```
build_container:
    stage: build
    ....
    ....
    only:
      changes:
        - Dockerfile
```

How would be a good way to make it run only on certain branches?

thanks

Comment: Use the `rules`?

Comment: @GaëlJ ok thanks, but I am new with this, how should I add a rule to for instance, if the branch name contains something like `container`

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948990/gitlab-ci-pipeline-on-specific-branch-only

Comment: If you want to just avoid running when creating new branches in the UI, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77499265/5747944